django пользователь не может залогиниться Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /users/login/
Создал проект. На локалке работает без проблем, но при размещении на удаленном хосте, возникла проблема при входе для пользователей. Появилась ошибка:

Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /admin/login/.

Ошибка не стабильная, при первом входе появляется на всех устройствах. В дальнейшем, где-то остается, где-то все работает нормально.
login.html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-error">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
    {% for f in form %}
    <p><label class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{f.label}}: </label>{{ f }}</p>
    <div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><button type="submit">Войти</button></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'users:password_reset' %}">Забыли пароль?</a></p>
</form>

view.py
class LoginUser(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginUserForm
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    extra_context = {'title': 'Авторизация'}

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('start_page')

urls.py
path('login/', views.LoginUser.as_view(), name='login')


Мидлваре не включен

Исходя из предоставленной строчки из лога ошибки довольно трудно предположить из за чего конкретно происходит ошибка с csrf токеном. Попробуйте методом подбора задать вручную настройки токена в файле settings.py. Вот одно из решений проблемы:
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None'

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True

Вот ссылка на нужный кусок текста в документации фреймворка

Спасибо. Но уже разобрался с проблемой.

Проблема была в том, что при написании ссылки на ресурс в разных браузерах, я не указывал протокол (http/https). Некоторые браузеры подставляли http - и я получал ошибку; другие - https, и тогда все работало корректно.
